# Why dont the observers catch the fugitives?

Tags: fringe

In season 5,

> There is a cat and mouse game between the observers and the fugitives (main characters), where the fugitives repeatedly escape just in time.
> In some cases the observers even catch a glimpse of the fugitives taking off.

When this happens, why dont the observers just go back in time for a minute or 10?

Comment: It was ridiculous how the Observers couldn't do anything useful at all unless the plot required it. Why keep taking lifts all the time if you can just teleport about at will? How come Windmark can accurately predict Peter's movements for about twenty minutes of the season, but can't find the fugitives for any of the rest of it? It was all rather silly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the last episodes Windmark wanted to do that, but the chief administrator didn't let him, because they are very careful about changing something in the past.

Also it is a TV series, that happens.